# How to remove ActiveX which is preventing the sending of compressed photos

Tags: activex

I am trying to send compressed photos as attachments to my hotmail e-mails.  I am blocked from doing so because of ActiveX.  This problem has only started recently and the only downloads to my computer have been from recognised and trusted sources. Is it possible to find where in the system this ActiveX control is and how can I remove it?  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a problem you're having with internet explorer?  You should probably just switch to a better browser like [firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/en-US/firefox/firefox.html) or [chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/intl/en/landing_chrome.html?hl=en).

Answer (score 0):

There are some possible solutions:

- If you are using Internet Explorer 6, you can [disable ActiveX controls from running](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/ie/ie6/using/howto/security/setup.mspx#ELAAE) in the Security tab of the Internet Options dialog.
- If you are using Internet Explorer 7 or 8, you can [disable addons](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Internet-Explorer-add-ons-frequently-asked-questions) or [reset Internet Explorer's settings](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923737). Either of these should fix the issue.

If all of these fail, you could use another browser, like [Mozilla Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com) or [Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) as a workaround. Both of these browsers do not support ActiveX.